# ResourceManager getString without passing bundle

Tags: apache-flex

In Flex is there a way to use the ResourceManager without having the pass in the bundle?

We have a number of bundles that we load up and save, But we always have to reference with

```
bundleName = 'Bundle1';
token = 'token_test1'
parameters = null
locale = null
ResourceManager.getInstance().getString(bundleName,token,parameters,locale)
```

I would love to get to the point where we don't need to pass the bundle.  I know we have three bundles loaded, but I just want token 'x'.  Last one in wins type of thing.  Is there any way to do this other then to load everything into the same bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this is possible, you always have to pass the bundle (we prefer to keep them all in one single file).

FYI: [Lupo Manager](https://github.com/davidderaedt/lupo-studio/tree/master/LupoMgr) is a great (AIR) tool to manage resource files.

Comment: After more research I realized that I didn't have a very good understanding of the ResourceBundle.  The key to what I wanted was to actually load different files or bundle groups into a single bundle.  So in my case I might have three translation files that need to be combined, if I load them all into the same bundle I have a single place to pull translation from.